# Mac Chrome add border to image

Tags: css, html

A grey border gets added to the 3 hexagonal image to the bottom and right side after animation in Mac Chrome:

[image: Issue]

Client is running:
Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117
running on OS X Mavericks MacBook Pro 13", model  A1502 running OS X Maverick

A video of issue is here:
http://youtu.be/UDnf_0wkzqQ

Website Location:
http://lightpolymers.com.s171316.gridserver.com

Is there a solution?

Comment: similar question here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743127/chrome-safari-display-border-around-image

Comment: I am also using a Mac OS X Mavericks, Chrome 33.0.1750.117, and I don't see the gray border.

Comment: I have tested it with browserstack and saw no line -> but in the video it shows that the client has clearly cleared their browser and the border occurs. He has also sent 3 screeencasts of the same issue on three different macs running the system above.

Safari is fine.

Comment: Throwing this here just like this. Have you tried `border`? `border-style`? `outline`? `box-shadow`? Have you tried `!important`?

Comment: Hi Ariane - I'll send to the client and see - but I am sure I did: http://lightpolymers.com.s171316.gridserver.com/new-css.html

The problem is I can't test it - as I don't have the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it as I moved the animation css from the image to its parent's div and it works.

Animating the image seems to add the ghost gray border.