# Safari shows gray border around <img/>, even though image exists

Tags: css, safari

[image: Gray border]

There is a gray border showing around the dropdown image, as seen above. That shouldn't be there. I've seen [several other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743127/chrome-safari-display-border-around-image) which state that this is the case because the `src` of the image cannot be found or loaded. However, that's not the case here. The element contains a `src` tag which is set to a 16x16 blank GIF.

[image: Image is fine]

The file '/images/system/blank.gif' exists, and can be loaded by Safari. Also shows up fine in the Network panel, as 200 -  OK.

However, and here is the reason of the bug I guess... In the elements panel the image shows up as:

[image: Weird, 0 x 0 natural]

I can load this image fine in Safari, opening it in a new tab shows as 16x16 GIF... No idea what's going on here.

Just FYI, this is Safari only. Chrome does not show the gray border around the image.

**Note:** Changing to a transparent PNG image solves the issue, but I'd like to know the underlying cause.

Comment: `Natural 0x0` I suppose your gif may have some problem. Should it not be at least 1x1 ?

Comment: The gif is 16x16... When I open the image in a new tab Safari shows it as such as well. Same for Chrome...

Comment: when you embed the blank gif in the page how it's recognized by Safari? What is its mime-type? Are you sure you have not saved that image as a png with a wrong extension?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I removed the querystring param and included it in the page and it worked. It looks like it indeed is something with content type. No Content-Type header is added to the response. However, when you include `/images/system/blank.gif` Safari manages to find out what the image is, but if you add `?v=123` it no longer does.

Answer (score 0):

Tracked down the issue to... uBlock!

uBlock decided that an image in the form of `/images/system/blank.gif?v=12345` was an ad and decided to cancel the request. The joy.