# How to remove white border on lazy loaded images in Safari

Tags: html, css, image, safari, lazy-loading

I'm adding some native lazy loading to images on a website using the standard `loading="lazy"` tag. It works fine and does the job I want, but in Safari (desktop and mobile) the images prior to loading in have a white border that I cannot seem to get rid of. It only appears for a brief flicker as you scroll, but is particularly obvious and annoying on an otherwise dark website!

It appears to be the same thing that happens if an image fails to load, and can be replicated by disabling images using Safari's "develop" menu.

I've tried to remove this with all the CSS I can think of...

```
border: none !important;
outline: none !important;
border-color: #000 !important;
```

... but no luck getting rid of it.

Anyone able to help? Is this even possible? Thanks

*Example of how this looks:*

[image: Example of white border on an image]

Comment: Most likely, Safari assigns some kind of temporary box for the image. And that box has a border. There would be some sort of border styling in the user style-sheet defined by the browser.

Comment: What version of Safari and OS?

Comment: @morganney its obviously Mac OS unless u mean which IDE or software... they probably use VSCode

Comment: @RagDev you obviously don't know that both Safari and MacOS have different versions.

Comment: Please try this one box-shadow: none !important;

Comment: @morganney unless they have an rare old MacOS system then it should always update to the newest OS and that is not a old feature especially since you can't get good coding softwares on an older system without it dying and Safari does have other versions but why does that matter because no one usually takes their time to download the Safari app since they already either have FireFox,Internet Explorer or Google Chrome

Comment: @RagDev you want to develop for the web and ask why browser versions matter? Ok.

Comment: because... its most likely up to date since it has the updated css webkit

Comment: This happens in at least iOS 15 and Safari 15 on both macOS Monterey and macOS Catalina

Comment: @AshokK unfortunately changing the box shadow in any way makes no difference

Comment: This looks like a bug. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=243601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered here: [chrome/safari display border around image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743127/chrome-safari-display-border-around-image)

Simon_Weaver gave a detailed answer with solutions for lazy load conditions if you scroll down below the primary answer.

Comment: Thanks, this option using JS does look to probably be the best workaround - there doesn't seem to be any other way using just CSS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You can also use the "Share" link in the answer to have a direct link to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68614653/1895428

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug in Safari 15: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=243601

Here's a hack using `clip-path` to remove the edge of the image if Safari is detected:

```css
@supports (font: -apple-system-body) and (-webkit-appearance: none) {
  img[loading="lazy"] {
    clip-path: inset(0.6px)
  }
}
```

The bug was fixed [a few versions ago](https://twitter.com/othermaciej/status/1618296591475183616) but it wasn't released to stable until [Safari 16.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes)

Answer (score 0):

You could look up [Safari Webkits](https://webkit.org/) to to change certain things like a scroll bar and more.

Comment: https://webkit.org/