# annoying styling issue with ie7 & 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

on the following page:

http://dreamdeals.rnmtest.co.uk/

the login box on the right displays fine in firefox, ie8, safari, chrome etc but in ie7 & 6 the contents overflow. I have tried everything such as setting a height for the inputs but cant get it right. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by overflow? I looked at it in IE7 and it seems to be displaying the same as IE8, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I see no problem in IE7. Can you attach a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: probably ie7 on compatibility mode?

Comment: floating the inputs element may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this idea seems to at first glance make about as much sense as chopping off your own arms, but:

- On `#whyjoin input`, instead of `border: none`, try using `border: 0`.

Here's a reference to the problem you're having:

- http://bitesizebugs.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/border-none-not-working-on-text-input-in-internet-explorer/

---

So, despite `border: 0` being the same as `border: none`, it's better use `0` because it's shorter and to avoid this bug.

[I should probably go post that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922909/should-i-use-border-none-or-border-0)

Comment: well i never! It worked! Never heard of that one before but I'll certainly have to remember it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my IE8 (7 compatibilty mode), it's work fine ; But try to modify your height like this:

```
#whyjoin {
    background-image: url(../images/whyjoinback.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 30px 5px 0 5px;
    height: 70px; /* BG Image (100px) = 70px + 30px (padding) */
    margin-top: -55px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I Suggest you to place the `#cardclip` in absolute to not poluate the `#rightcol`.