# Textbox style different on localhost and web server

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, localhost

The following code on a remote web server renders an "invisible" textbox as expected. However the same code on localhost still shows the textbox borders. There are no other stylesheets coming into play (that I am aware of) - and `!important` has no effect.

```
<input type="text" style="color:White; border:none; width:1px;" />
```

I found [this discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/633948-display-different-when-calling-localhost-internally-externally) which suggests using instead `border-left: none`, `border-right: none` etc. This works!! But I'm still posting here because I don't understand why. The page on the server is identical, and being viewed on the same browser (IE8).

Any thoughts?

Comment: On localhost, are you viewing the page through a server or just opening up the html page in your browser directly? It could be something to do with the headers that the server sends, perhaps a doctype issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the remote server, IE8 is in "IE8 Mode", so it works as expected.

For whatever reason, on localhost IE8 is in "IE7 Mode".

Hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools to verify this.

Possible causes:

- You hit the Compatibility Mode button when viewing the page from localhost.
- Otherwise, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx or http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8modes.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long shot, but if the local host and web server are compiling the code differently it may be worth trying border: 0; instead or border: none; in the styling.

Comment: [They do the same thing.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922909/should-i-use-border-none-or-border-0)