# Last-child selector with border still leaves th underlined

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, border, css-selectors

I would really appreciate some help.

I have a problem with html markup in asp.net, so, have to make workaround. For Firefox and Opera, everything is perfect, but Chrome on Safari still have one issue.

I want to make last `<th>` tag unbordered. Header `<tr>` line has "bordered" css class. Here is css part:

```
.bordered th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.bordered th:last-child
{
    border: 0px none white;
    border-bottom: 0px none white;    
}
```

HTML markup:

```
`<table class="bordered" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_body_gvTimeTable" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="border-width:0px;">
        <th scope="col">One</th>
        <th scope="col">Two</th>
        <th scope="col">Three</th>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>`
```

But still last `<th>` stays underlined. What's the problem?

Comment: I do not observe this problem in the latest versions of Chrome and Safari for OSX.

Comment: Sorry, I can't show whole project, only one screen http://i27.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1127/ca/97d55867500ba95d28865b641e4f6bca.png

Comment: Or here is example http://codepaste.ru/8500/. Problem is that I can't modify HTML markup, it's asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this out in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nswah/2/).  I wasn't able to see any problem in Chrome (version 15) nor Safari (version 5).

I made a slight adjustment to your CSS (changed your border values to zero - as suggested by [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922909/should-i-use-border-none-or-border-0)):

```
.bordered th { border: 1px solid black; }
.bordered th:last-child { border: 0; border-bottom: 0; }
```

Something to note, :last-child is a [CSS3 selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).  That means it will not work in IE8 or below (unless you are using [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) or similar).

Comment: It only appears if the next row is fully spanned, even if the row isn't bordered.

Answer (score 0):

`:last-child` will select the last child element of the targeted parent (in this case, `.bordered th`). You'll need to use something like `th:last-of-type`.

Comment: It's still affected by css, but I think it's Chrome bug, that it still remain bottom border line.

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing it an `!important` this will override any previously given stylings, aswell as stylings that would override it later on.

```
.bordered th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.bordered th:last-child
{
    border: 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```