# Border: none works in IE8 but not IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, border

I have text inputs with 1px padding that I sometimes put 1 px borders on. I want all text inputs to fill the same vertical space, borders or not. To achieve that, I created a "don't have borders, but fill space like you do" class with border: none and 2px of padding:

```
.BorderInputNone {
 border: none;
 padding: 2px;
}
```

This worked in IE8, but in IE7, there were visible borders around the input.

**EDIT: I fixed it by using border: transparent.**

```
.BorderInputNone {
border: 1px solid transparent;
padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: What's the HTML? Is it a submit button or a text input field?

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question body.

Comment: Will you put your sample HTML code here   http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I want inputs to fill the same space, borders or not.

Comment: If you've solved this problem, please post your solution below as an answer and then "accept" your own answer.

Comment: I need 100 karma to self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using border: transparent.

```
.BorderInputNone {
border: 1px solid transparent;
padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `border: 0px;` as it seems more cross browser compatible.

Check this question here  [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922909/should-i-use-border-none-or-border-0)

Here is an example for you to fix IE7:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Uee/