# BootStrap Customization

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to make (well.. in the process of making..) a tabbed page. I made a "tabbed box" with the border-top:none property so it looks like it's a part of the tabs, and inside of that I have a table.

I was wondering, is there a way to remove ALL borders (except bottom) of the table headers, but keep all surrounding borders on all table data cells? The table header borders are conflicting with the 'seamless' aspect of the tab box I created. Here is my code (using bootstrap 3). If you know any classes that would replace all this, great, if not, some CSS guidance would be exceptional.

```
<div style="width:95%; margin:0 auto;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#uno" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#dos" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tres" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" style="width:99.9%; margin:0 auto; outline: 1px solid #ddd">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="uno">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter">
                <thead>

                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade in"id="dos">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter">
                <thead>

                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tres">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter">
                <thead>

                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note I removed table content just for the sake of clean code, I just left the structure in tact.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/pzzey/

Comment: That removed the tab borders, I asked for the table header borders (<th>)

Comment: That was just the same code you posted. I just put it into a fiddle for the benefit of other viewers. (And so I could work on it)

Comment: This doesn't happen to be what you want does it: `th{border-top:0px solid transparent!important;border-left:0px solid transparent!important;border-right:0px solid transparent!important; }` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/hc45U/2/)

Comment: SORT OF!! First: what is !important? Second: It does not remove the top border, nor the outside borders. It did remove the inside header borders though, so it's very close

Comment: I modified your code, replacing 0px solid transparent with "hidden" and that worked. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it when I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the css you're looking for:

```
table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th,
table.table-bordered {
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
    border-top:0;
}
```

This should remove the top, left, and right borders from the table and th elements.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/hc45U/8/

Comment: !important should be avoided at all costs. It is a nuclear option in CSS.

Comment: @SeanRyan Yes, but without knowing the future structure of the OP's html, it's the only thing I can guarantee to work. I've added an alternative solution.

Comment: Well, you don't need to know the future structure, you just need to know the specificity of Bootstrap's CSS, and then match or beat to override it.

Comment: @SeanRyan Got it, I figured out how to do it without `!important`.

Comment: Also, rather than doing `0px solid transparent`, why not just do `none`?

Comment: Not sure why you didn't use `none` but the selectors work perfectly. Once I read up what `!important` was I ditched it, not worth a nuclear explosion lol

Comment: @SeanRyan @RUJordan `border:none` is known to be less compatible (won't work in IE<8). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10538111/1721527

Comment: Actually, it looks like `border:0` will work: http://bitesizebugs.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/border-none-not-working-on-text-input-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Regarding none not being <IE8 compatible, I'll repeat my comment to my own answer: It is a waste of time to avoid simple answers just to achieve pixel perfection on 7+ year old browsers. If it does not impede the ability of a user to access the site information, then let it degrade gracefully.

Comment: @SeanRyan True, but `border:0` works on IE7 and is shorter than `border:none` too.

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the `.table-bordered` class, and then add back the right hand border on all cells but the last one. The relevent CSS:

```
.table tbody tr td:not(:last-child),
.table thead tr th:not(:last-child) {
    border-right:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

A working example: http://bootply.com/85323

Comment: IE<9 doesn't support the `:not` pseudo-class: http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#link5

Comment: Being that it does not impede function, in my mind that is irrelevant. Avoiding simple solutions to make a design pixel perfect on a browser that is seven years old is not a good use of resources.