# Need to remove image border

Tags: css, image, border, href

I'm needing to remove the border above the scrolling images here: http://briansmall.com/inovar/capabilities-test.html

Trouble is, my style.css (line 367) seems to trump my screen.css, and I can't remove the border without removing it from the #left-nav a (on the same page), which I don't want to do.

Can anyone help me remove the border-top from the img on this particular page?  I hope I'm making sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this  `img{border: 0}`

**Edited**

Look into these:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: More than likely, this border is going to appear somewhere in one of the slider's imported stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

I appears you have `border: 0 none;`, not sure what you're trying to do here (you should pick one: [Should I use 'border: none' or 'border: 0'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922909/should-i-use-border-none-or-border-0)) , but if you set your css to:

`img { border: 0 !important; }`

in your stylesheet, that should override your inline style and remove the border on all sides.

Comment: Well, I've added 
img { border: 0 !important; } 
a img { border: 0 !important; } in screen.css, but, I'm still getting the border.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove border from parent of your `<img>`. In this case from your `<a>` tag

set your border in `#left-nav a` to `none`

OR

if you can't edit it, you can add new element rule for your `<a>` in slide show and set

`border: none !important;`

Comment: I appreciate your response.  However, I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed. I'm not sure I know where (exactly) you mean to make the change. Can you attempt to spell it out for me?

Comment: edit it in your style.css but I still don't understand why you can't remove the border without removing it from the #left-nav a

Comment: In order for the navigation on the left to have the thin border that separates each menu item, I have border-top:1px solid #dadcde set in the #left-nav a.  That's what is causing the same border above the images I'm talking about. That's what's got me all tangled up.

Comment: okay, maybe you can try to add new rule for your `<a>` in your slide show