# Strange border line in IE8 that I didn't add

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

[image]

Same HTML, CSS, and image file, but in IE8 I have this weird border line.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="admin_link_div">
    <ul id="vertical_menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/admin/appointment_list">
            <div id="sidebar_left_box">
                Room List
            </div><img id="admin_arrow_img_roomlist" src="/images/arrow_off_icon.gif"></a>
        </li><div id="sidebar_line"></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <div id="sidebar_left_box">
                User Management
            </div><img id="admin_arrow_img_userlist" src="/images/arrow_off_icon.gif"></a>
            <br>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/admin/users">User List</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/admin/users/multi_register">User Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li><div id="sidebar_line"></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <div id="sidebar_left_box">
                Company Mangement
            </div><img id="admin_arrow_img_register" src="/images/arrow_off_icon.gif"></a>
            <br>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/admin/companies">Company List</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/admin/companies/new">Company Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li><div id="sidebar_line"></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <div id="sidebar_left_box">
                Service Management
            </div><img id="admin_arrow_img_service" src="/images/arrow_off_icon.gif"></a>
            <br>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/admin/barbie_servers">Server Management</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/admin/barbie_management">Barbie Management</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#admin_arrow_img_userlist{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Any good reason???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this to your image `#`

```
outline:none;
border: none;
```

because IE sets a border for images by default!!

Comment: isn't it usually `border`, not outline?

Comment: @yochannah : both `border` and `outline` should be `none`, cause IE sets the default value for them....agreed with your point!! :)

Comment: Thanks for the SUPER FAST response. cuz it was so fast i have to wait to select the answer :) have to wait 10 min

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS on image

```
img
{
 border:0;
 outline:none; 
}
```

Use border `0` **[Check link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2922909/1328612)** more appropriate.