# Why doesn't the browser accept part of my CSS code?

Tags: html, css

Here's a part of my CSS code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
```

When I tried to run the code I noticed (when I tried debugging) that there is a line on the font-size, and the font Why?

Comment: What about an ending `}` ?

Comment: it's just a part of the code....I have }in the end

Answer (score 0):

use

```
border: none;
```

instead of

```
border: 0;
```

Comment: According to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2922934/1016777). They are equivalent in effect.

Comment: it helps only for the font.

Comment: I have also lines on:-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: that is because they're not valid html. Because they're prefixed elements, nothing you can do about that.